# Generating Entity class from Column Family Definition

Tags: java, cassandra, entity, javassist

I'm trying to generate the entity class for a Cassandra column family from the column family definition (a .cql file), programmatically.

To achieve that I've used the [arch4j java code generator](http://arch4j.sourceforge.net/components/generator/index.html). But, unfortunately, I didn't find any solution to create annotations using this API. So, I used [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/index.html) to add annotations to the generated entity class. Again, as this Javassist API deals with the Java byte code, I had to use a Java decompiler (e.g. Procyon) to decompile the class file generated by Javassist.

Is there any simpler way to achieve my target?

Comment: So for what I understood you first generate java source code and you then compile it to use javassist. You can use java parser instead (http://javaparser.github.io/javaparser/) that works at source code level. That way you wouldn't need javassist not the decompile process. Maybe you could even just use java parser for everything and have a single tool.

Comment: I have tried using that API after you mentioned it, but I couldn't get a solution to programmatically generate getters, setters, hashCode, equals and toString methods using it. Can you help???

Comment: You can check their manual here: https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/wiki/Manual. Basicaly whatyou have to do is: 1. If you're parsing the code already generated by arch4j create a visitor that visits the class and created more MethodDeclarations. 2. If you're using only java parser for everything you'll have create your own CompilationUnit and then create all the MethodDeclarations and VariableDeclarations. Afterwards you'll have to to dump the CompilationUnit content.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But I ultimately used the [JavaPoet API](https://github.com/square/javapoet) and the [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to achive my purpose.. :)

Comment: Good :) Didn't know about JavaPoet API, looks nice as well. Please add an answer to your own question saying what you used and accept it so the question doesn't stay marked as unanswered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I took another approach towards solving my problem and ended up with [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) and [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/index.html) APIs. I've used JavaPoet to generate the .java file with the required annotations for the entity. Then I've processed that file using Lombok/Delombok to generate the getters, setters, hashCode, equals and toString methods.